# How do I omit empty (black) tiles from a QGIS raster export?

Tags: raster, export, georeferencing, tiles

At the moment I'm deleting these manually after export and I'm curious if there's another way.

I've currently imported a transparent TIFF layer and georeferenced it to Bing. I'm then exporting with Raster Tools > Generate XYZ Tiles (Directory).

This process is working great, but it's exporting all of the fully transparent (blank) areas as black files that I have to then manually delete later.

Is there some way to simply omit these during export?

Here's the example area if it's helpful for some reason:
[image]